# Не могу вспомнить - PHP - альтернатива ""

Tags: php

Помню как-то читал, что есть альтернатива **""** выглядит примерно так:

```
$a = <<READ
text jkdsdklvdkl
READ;
```

Но этот вариант не работает, напомните как правильно, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это heredoc, там должно быть 3 "<", заместо HEREDOC можно что угодно написать.

```
$a = <<<HEREDOC
text jkdsdklvdkl
HEREDOC;
```

Comment: Спасибо.
Но еще вопрос, где здесь ошибка, никак не могу разобраться? <code><?php
$str = <<<EOD
Пример строки,
охватывающей несколько строчек,
с использованием heredoc-синтаксиса.
EOD;

$fer = "строки";

$string = ereg_replace($fer," ",$str);
echo $string;

?>
</code>