# Как заключить обширный html в переменную?

Tags: php

Есть сформированный хтмл код, его очень много в файле, и в него встроены php условия, циклы и т.д.

Хочу этот весь код, обернуть в переменную, и кэшировать, это отдельный разговор, так вот, можно ли как-то взять хтмл код, и обернуть в одну переменную?

```
<div class="main">
    пхп условия, циклы, хтмл
</div>
```

Можно ли сделать, нечто подобное этому

```
<?php $html = EOT?>
    <div class="main">
        пхп условия, циклы, хтмл
    </div>
<?php EOT; ?>
```

Выбивает ошибку, ясное дело, но если можно было бы как-то сделать так - то было бы чудесно

Comment: Дубликат https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/43610/186083

Comment: + https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/127935/186083 ;)

Comment: @Visman Да, тот код, только под себя немного переделал

Answer (score 1):

Решение через буферизацию.

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>

html,php,db...

<?php 
    // В $html будет хранится все, что было выведено выше.
    $html = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
?>
```